# In Django, how to add creator of a group to that group instantly?

Tags: python, django, signals

I'm creating a 'social' app in Django, where the users can create groups (Alliances) and others can join these groups. User *Profiles* and *Alliances* are connected through *Membership* model. **I´d like the creator of such group to be a member of it instantly.**

I'm inexperienced in Django, in fact, this is my first project. But I figured that this maybe could be solved by signals?

My user Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alliances = models.ManyToManyField('Alliance', through='Membership')
    ...
```

My Alliance model:

```
class Alliance(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', through='Membership')
    ...
```

My Membership model:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    ...
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alliance = models.ForeignKey('Alliance', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

The solution I figured could work (using signals) would look something like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Alliance)
def create_membership(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Membership.objects.create(profile=???, alliance=instance)
```

Where the '???' should be the creators profile. I'll be really glad for any help.

Comment: I guess you should do that in the form. A signal has no access to a request, since it is not said that creating a group is done with a request in the first place.

Comment: That probably needs to be done in the view. Show the view that's creating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signal has no access to the request that triggered it, since it is not said that the trigger is a HTTP request in the first place. You could try to inspect the traceback, but that is a hacky solution that will probably generate more trouble than it is worth.

You will need to do that in the *form* or in the *view* where you create the group. For example in the view, you can add this with:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from app.models import Alliance, Membership

class AllianceCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Alliance

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        Membership.objects.create(
            profile=self.request.user.profile,
            alliance=self.object
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Note that the modeling is quite strange. Normally you do *not* specify two `ManyToManyField`s. Django will automatically add the second one. You thus can specify in your `Profile`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alliances = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Alliance',
        through='Membership',
        related_name='members'
    )
```

Comment: I see I've been thinking about it wrong. Your approach worked awesomely. Also, thank you for additional advice!

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do that in a model's method instead of the view to follow the _"thick models thin views"_ rule ?

Comment: @Elias: no, the main difference between models and views is that models are written *request-unaware*. If the request is necessary, than a rule of thumb is to do the request-necessary effects in the view.